# Migrating from jersey to spring-mvc/rest: ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I need to migrate from jersey to spring-mvc/rest in cause of business requirements ...

I am searching in spring-mvc for something that is equivalent to jersey's `ContainerRequestFilter`, `ContainerResponseFilter`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, how did you make it finally? I'm confusing with same trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605057/migrate-jersey-to-spring-boot-however-blocking-by-filters

Comment: @Junjie I conviced my customer using jersey for this. :) Sorry.

Comment: Thank you all the same @t777 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). You won't find it in the two-class request/response flavor, but both filter methods are included in the same class, in the form of `preHandle` and `postHandle`, which is the equivalent of request-`filter` and response-`filter`, respectively. The interceptor wraps the handler call. Here's an example:

Interceptor:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

public class LogginHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest hsr, 
                             HttpServletResponse hsr1, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("preHandle - " + handler);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1, 
                           Object handler, ModelAndView mav) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("postHandle - " + handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1, 
                                Object handler, Exception excptn) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterCompletion - " + handler);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
public class WebAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LogginHandlerInterceptor());
    }
    ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Intercepting Requests with HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)
- [MVC Config Interceptors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-interceptors)

Comment: FYI you can extend HandlerInterceptorAdaptor to avoid having to implement no-op methods if all you care about is overriding one method, pre or post

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated in Spring 5. Now you can implement WebMvcConfigurer interface because it is full of Java 8's default methods