# migrate jersey to spring boot however blocking by filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey

I need to migrate our project from jersey to spring boot because of business requirements.

However, there are lots of filters like below,

```
public class BasicFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter { {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    }
    // ...
}
```

I think it should be regarded as `HandlerInterceptor` in spring, as you known, I can rewrite these filters following spring rules, but it very very heavy and error-prone, so, is there any way to integrate with these filter easily without overwriting?

Highly appreciated for your suggestion.

Comment: Why would you need to rewrite those? You are using Jersey then use Jersey. The fact that you use Jersey doesn't mean you cannot use Spring Boot (it even has auto configuration and support for Jersey).

Comment: Do you mean you have a requirement to switch to spring-mvc? This is different than the requirement to switch to spring-boot. These are two completely different animals which are used for different purposes. As M.Deinum said, spring-boot can be used with Jersey. But if the requirement is to switch to spring-mvc, that's a different story.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your suggestion, I followed it already.

Comment: @peeskillet  I switched to spring boot. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I think you might have a misunderstanding of what Spring Boot is exactly. It is not a REST framework. It is simply a bootstrapping framework. You need to add a REST framework to it if you want to run a REST application. Spring Boot is not tied to any single REST framework. It can be used with Spring MVC or it can be used with Jersey. There is no default. From my perspective, it sounds like you have a requirement to switch to Spring MVC (using Spring Boot). This is reason for my comment. Otherwise, if I am wrong, then just use Jersey with Spring Boot. No need to convert anything.

Comment: @peeskillet Your comments really helps me a lot to understand spring boot clearly. I have used spring boot years ago and it works well together with spring MVC. As mentioned above, I have integrated spring boot with jersey already, however, my previous goal is to convert jersey to Spring MVC and then integrate with spring boot. Actually, I didn't find any solution. I think I'm sure that what I want to know is to convert a jersey project easily to Spring MVC.

Comment: There's really no easy way. You pretty much need a complete rewrite

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for your confirmation, man.