# What is the equivalent part of Jersey ClientRequestContext and ClientResponseContext in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, jersey

I want to migrate my application from Jersey to Spring MVC, What is the equivalent part of Jersey ClientRequestContext and ClientResponseContext in Spring MVC? It is Jersey client side filter, does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one to one mapping for these classes in Spring. You can achieve this by implementing HandlerInterceptor.
Check if [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640331/migrating-from-jersey-to-spring-mvc-rest-containerrequestfilter-containerrespo) gets you going.